# Still posting back after javascript return false in switch

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, switch-statement

I'm trying to check to make sure some fields in the footer of a repeater aren't blank when trying to add a line to the repeater. I'm attempting to validate this through javascript, with reusable code for several different repeaters (by abusing IDs):

```
switch (category)
        {
            case 'Hardware':
                if ($("#HWtable").find("#AddProduct").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddPartNumber").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddPartCost").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddUnitPrice").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddQuantity").val() == null) 
                {
                    alert("show HW message");
                    HWEmptyFieldAlert.show();
                    return false;
                }
                break;
```

The problem is that it is still posting back even though I have the return false there. I also included it in my clientclick call:

```
onClientClick="return EmptyFieldCheck('Hardware');"
```

If I comment out the switch and just say return false, everything works as expected. My best guess is that I'm just returning out of the if or the switch, and not the post back. How do I go about doing this properly?

EDIT: Per other's suggestions below, I tried a flag and reversing the true/false state at the client click. What I now have below is still posting back and I really don't know why. I do see the alert when I click, so it's getting that far.

```
var emptyFlag;

        switch (category)
        {
            case 'Hardware':
                /*
                if ($("#HWtable").find("#AddProduct").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddPartNumber").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddPartCost").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddUnitPrice").val() == null ||
                   $("#HWtable").find("#AddQuantity").val() == null)
                {
                */
                    alert("show HW message");
                    HWEmptyFieldAlert.show();
                    emptyFlag = false;
                //}
                break;
            default:
                alert("doesn't work");
                return false;
                break;
        }

        return emptyFlag;
```

Does this have something to do with me using the OnItemCommand function of the repeater? Returning false instead of emptyFlag is no longer working. OnClientClick="return false;" does stop the postback though.

Comment: You do realize that `id`s must be **unique** as per-document? If you did, you'd realize that `$("#HWtable").find("#AddProduct")` will always do the same as `$("#AddProduct")`.

Comment: Only empty selects have a val() of null

Comment: @connexo would this not look for #AddProduct within HWTable? that was my intent. I have several other tables with the same line. I mentioned that I was abusing the IDs to reuse the code for other tables. It's worked in other functions at least

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! hadn't made it that far, but I'm sure I would have learned quickly. One of them is a select so it hadn't failed yet. I will adjust for textboxes.

Comment: **You cannot have more than one instance of any given id in an HTML document.** Use ***classes*** instead.

Comment: @connexo you should be more clear about what you're actually saying. After googling, I learned that i _shouldn't_ have more than one element with a given ID. I get that, I can make the change in the future, now can we fix the postback issue at hand?

Comment: @Jordan How can "`id`s must be **unique** per-document" be any clearer?

Comment: @ErikE easy. "W3C spec does not allow for multiple elements to use the same ID" The issue here is jargon. I've never heard per-document used in that fashion. I wasn't trying to be rude, I just didn't understand. It's a common mistake made when someone of a much higher understanding attempts to explain things to people like myself. 

It would be very easy for me to say something that i think is obvious if we were talking motorcycles, and you could look at me like i'm stupid if you didn't know what i know. 

I've seen people say use classes before, but it never made sense why I needed to.

Comment: @JordanWayneCrabb On the one hand, I sympathize with you and don't want you to feel put down; on the other hand, the person did the best he could to give you exactly the information you needed, and your comment was (to me) unduly critical.

Comment: @ErikE definitely unintentional. I was clarifying for other novices that may find this thread in time. But to be fair, the information I need is still about this postback issue, not the use of IDs. Updating OP with progress.

Comment: your `default` still has `return false;` in it, it isn't setting the flag.

Comment: @ErikE I just hadn't changed it, it's not even hitting that part of the code. It's hitting the Hardware case

Answer (score 1):

In this case yes indeed the `return false` is returning from the `switch` and not the entire function. What you wan to do is create a flag variable and when you want to return from the function after the switch, check the flag:

```
function EmptyFieldCheck( .. )
{
    var returnFlag = false;
    switch (category) {
        case 'Hardware':
            if(..)
            {
                ...
                returnFlag = true;
            }
            break; 
        ...
    }
    if(returnFlag) return false; 
    /* Other posting code here */
}
```

Comment: this seems logical but it still posts back, with and without the other answer included.

Answer (score 1):

Let's figure out where your bug comes from:

- Returning `false` from `EmptyFieldCheck` has the expected behavior, so there are no "wireup" issues here
- Your switch doesn't seem to work, so the bug is in there
- The `return false` statement in your switch is within an `if`
- So the `if` must be evaluating to false
- Which means `$("#HWtable").find("#x").val() == null` is always `false`, even if you *think* it isn't

`jQuery.val()` won't return a `null` if a field is empty. An empty field is a zero-length string (i.e. `""`), so this comparison is probably more suitable:

```
$("#HWtable").find("#x").val().length === 0
```

If you check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3ekses2/) you'll see that:

```
$input.val(""); // Set to empty
$input.val() == null; // returns false, not true, as your code suggests
```

Which is in-line with the guess. So your fixed code should contain:

```
$("#HWtable").find("#AddPartNumber").val().length === 0 ||
$("#HWtable").find("#AddPartCost").val().length === 0 ||
// etc.
```

Or, if you really want to avoid any wierd bugs further down the line:

```
$("#HWtable").find("#AddPartNumber").val().trim().length === 0 ||
$("#HWtable").find("#AddPartCost").val().trim().length === 0 ||
// etc.
```

Because `.trim()` will both remove whitespace and also throw an exception if `.val()` happens to return something that is not a string (e.g. in wierd circumstances with empty selectors or multiselect controls).

Comment: I think this is definitely an improvement in design for the textboxes, but the if IS evaluating to true, as I do still see the alert pop up before the postback goes through. I think this is because one of the elements checked is a select that does return null when empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!EmptyFieldCheck('Hardware')) { return false; } else { return true; }
```

I've seen the .NET client library have issues when just returning a function call directly, but never bothered to look into why.